# Show a name from associated class in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, show

I have Aulas and Students Through Grades,

in grades I want to display the name of the student and the name of the Aula.

```
<% @grades.each do |grade| %>
    <%= grade.student.name %>
    <%= grade.aula.name %>
<% end %>
```

If I leave only the student I get it perfect, But when I want to get Aula name, I get:

```
undefined method `aula' for #<#<Class:0x30a37e8>:0x2fffeb0>
```

Here is my code

```
class Aula < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :grades
  has_many :students, :through => :grades
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :grades
  has_many :aulas, :through => :grades
end

class Grade < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :grammar, :oral, :participation, :writing
  belongs_to :aula
  belongs_to :student
end
```

I figure that the problem is that if `grade.aula.name` is nil, I get this error. If the data is there, it works perfectly.

How can I do an action like, `if grade.aula.name.nill? grade.aula.name = 'write the name here'`?

Comment: What is the output when you write just `<%= grade.aula %>` ?

Comment: It gives me `#<Aula:0x33a11a8>`

Comment: And if you write `<%= grade.aula.id%>` will it return an id of aula, please try.

Comment: Now, changed for name, and i get the correct rosult. Is this a cache error?

Comment: Can't say for sure, may be a restart was required.

Comment: thanks Anyway. Should I delete this post?

Comment: You can leave it for others. Cheers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to access the data from a connection in has\_many through?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17665301/how-to-access-the-data-from-a-connection-in-has-many-through)