# How do I access the data from a link in an association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, has-many-through

I have:

```
Aulas
has_many :grades
has_many :students, :through => :grades

Students
has_many :grades
has_many :aulas, :through => :grades

Grades
belongs_to :aula
belongs_to :student
```

I want to show `grades.name` from the conection between that Aula and a specific Student inside the Aula. This doesn't work, but you will understand what I want:

```
<% aula.students.each do |student| %>
  <%= link_to student.name, student %>-<%= student.grade.name %>
<% end %>
```

Ok so, i'm inside Aula (id:68) if I do students.grades, I get the grades from all Aulas

```
[#<Grade id: 51, name: AA1, student_id: 22, aula_id: 68 >,#<Grade id: 52, name: AA2, student_id: 22, aula_id: 69 >,#<Grade id: 53, name: AA3, student_id: 22, aula_id: 70 >]
```

How do i get only the name of the grade related to this Aula (aula_id:68)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I figured that instead of getting the name of the Grade throught Students, i can get the student through grades, so I did

```
<% aula.grades.each do |grade| %>
  <%= link_to grade.student.name, student %>-<%= grade.name %>
<% end %>
```

Now it roks just fine.

Answer (score 1):

A student `has_many :grades` (with a 's'), so when you have a `student` record, you cannot call `grade` (without 's') on it, because Rails don't know which grade you are looking for.

What you need to do is to call `student.grades` (with a 's'), that will inform Rails that you are looking at all gradeS of this student.

But it's not finish yet, because with `student.grades` you are getting all grades of this student. You have 2 solutions:

*Either* you want to show them all and you must loop through them, like this:

```
<% student.grades.each do |grade| %>
  <%= grade.name %>
  <br />
<% end %>
```

*Either* you are looking for one specific grade in your collection and you want to show only this one (let's imagine you are looking for the grade with id=5), you would do like this:

```
<%= student.grades.find(5).name %>
```

Also I would advise you to use the specific vocabulary, it is good so it will help you to find the correct information when you search in google for a solution. Here you are talking about connection between models, in Rails word we call it association :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, maybe that's why I'm having a hard time to find the answers.
But this doesn't solve all my problem.
The problem is that each grade is a link, how can I get the ID from that specific grade that makes the link? Aula-grade-student. If I get all the grades, I'll have handreds of them. I just want the one that makes the link. Is that possible?

Comment: Allan, you completely changed the question, I answered your previous question and I guess it works. If you want additional help on something else (here: links and IDs) create a new request. Thanks to validate my answer also